Why can the Linux header file declare struct and then use it?
I have a question when reading the linux source code(version:5.17.4): Why can the Linux header file declare struct and then use it?. Take ipv4.h for example, It seems to declare ctl_table_header/fib_table/sock first without including the corresponding header files, but use them later in the following struct definition. In C language, the definition of the data structure must be included before it can be used. This rule is not followed here. Why does it work normally?
Thanks in advance.

Can you share a code snippet that demonstrates this issue? It will make the question easier to understand.

Pointers to incomplete struct/union types are valid.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer

It's called a forward declaration, and can be used with a pointer.

The main reason this is done in large code bases such as the Linux kernel is to help minimise the number of nested #include directives in order to save compilation time.

The mechanism that allows this to work is that struct and union types are allowed to be declared as incomplete type, and the C standard requires all pointers to struct types to have the same representation and alignment requirements as each other, and requires all pointers to union types to have the same representation and alignment requirements as each other. So the representation and alignment requirement of the pointer type is known before the underlying type is completed (although the size and alignment requirement of the underlying struct or union type is not known until it is completed).

It can also be used to avoid some circular dependencies.

The C standard allows the declaration of an incomplete structure or union (6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers).
An incomplete struct/union declaration is composed simply by the name of the struct/union without the definition of any member.
An incomplete struct/union is an incomplete type (6.2.5 Types):

At various points within a translation unit an object type may be incomplete (lacking sufficient information to determine the size of objects of that type) or complete (having sufficient information).

This means that:

An incomplete type can only be used when the size of an object of that type is not needed.

I.e. a pointer to an incomplete type is perfectly legal (the size of a pointer is always defined).
The following snippet show the use of an incomplete structure definition:
struct incomplete_struct;         // an incomplete structure declaration
struct incomplete_struct *foo;    // a pointer to an incomplete structure definition
struct incomplete2 *bar;          // here we declare an incomplete structure and define a pointer to it

The standard also said (6.2.5 Types):

A type can be incomplete or complete throughout an entire translation unit, or it can change states at different points within a translation unit.

The state can be changed adding a complete declaration (that determines the size of the object) before using it. See the following example
struct incomplete *foo;          // declaration of incomplete structure and definition of a pointer to it
struct incomplete                // complete declaration of the structure
{
    int   a;
    float b;
};
foo->a = 0;                      // assign fields
foo->b = 0.0;

In this case the incomplete structure definition is referred to as forward declaration, and it is very useful to build definition of complex structures, or other objects, which refers to objects not yet defined (or that we don't need to specify in this specific translation unit, because we don't need them, or because these objects can change in different systems, etc.).
As a simple example consider the declaration of 2 structures that contains each a pointer to the other:
struct a               // complete type declaration for structure a
{
     struct b *foo;    // here we forward declare struct b and define a pointer to it
     ....              // other fields
};
struct b               // complete type declaration for structure b
{
     struct a *bar;
     ....              // other fields
};

The code above, while absolutely correct, couldn't be considered a good practice, because if the declarations of the 2 structures are sparse in the source file it exhibits a very poor readability. Personally, even if superfluous, I prefer to forward declare everything at start of translation unit making more easy to follow the code flow. I.e.:
struct a;               // forward declaration for structure a
struct b;               // forward declaration for structure b

.....

struct a               // complete type declaration for structure a
{
     struct b *foo;    // here we forward declare struct b and define a pointer to it
     ....              // other fields
};

.....

struct b               // complete type declaration for structure b
{
     struct a *bar;
     ....              // other fields
};


Thank you for your detailed and comprehensive answer, it gave me a good understanding of this question


In C language, the definition of the data structure must be included before it can be used.

Yes. But a pointer to the structure can be used without definition of the structure.

If it is a structure parameter of a function, does it have to include the corresponding header file?

Including a header file is just exactly the same as copy-pasting the file content. And no, it doesn't have to do anything, just forward declare the type to be used as a pointer.
